# Alert when a button is clicked?

Tags: jquery

I'd like to alert when an accessories button is clicked.

This is my current setup:

```
$(".btn").click(){
    alert("alert")
}
```

But I need to isolate the `.click` function to only trigger on the ID `#daccessories`

Solutions?

Comment: Just change `$(".btn")` to `$("#daccessories")`. This really is jQuery 101 though, which is why you're being downvoted. I would strongly suggest you read some guides: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/. Finally, note that you're missing a `)` at the end of the code block.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows lack of any research done. A simple google of "jquery button click by id" would suffice

Answer (score 0):

You missed to declare function inside click event and add id daccessories instead of .btn

```
$("#daccessories").click(function(){
    alert("alert");
});
```

Comment: dont forget the semicolon after `alert();`

Comment: its not necessary to add semicolon in jquery if we are writing all code in different line

Comment: @DharaParmar it will be an issue when your code is minified, and it's just good practice to do it anyway as it shows to other developers that you specifically intended to end the line here, and that nothing has been accidentally removed.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
$(".#daccessories").delegate(".btn", "click", function() {
    alert("Alert");
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use following code to bind click event for button this will worked**

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
    alert("alert")
});
```

**OR**

```
 $(".btn").on('click',function(){
        alert("alert")
 });
```